# Centered columns with fixed width using tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, width

How do I center the last seven columns in the attached text without dropping the fixed table width or the fixed column width?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,dcolumn,booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable, tabulary, tabularx, placeins,tocloft,tocbibind}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=1.5cm}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xsss|ssss}
\toprule
$\alpha$                &  & $ 1 $ & $ 2 $ & $ 3 $ & $ 4 $ & $ 5 $ & $ 6 $  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make this into a complete compilable example?

Comment: what is `s` ?  and do you just want `c` (which centres)

Comment: `\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=1.5cm}X}` (which you did not even show in the original version of the question) will entirely break `tabularx`. You can not use an `X` column to get a fixed width, the whole point of `X` is to get variable width.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. What should I then use to get a fixed column width while perserving the fixed table width in tabularx?

Comment: @Marcus see answer but I wouldn't use tabularx, the first column looks like it should just be `l` and you can use a normal tabular (or tabular*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `p` columns for fixed width, not `X` also there is not room for that many columns of `1.5cm` so I changed it to 1.1

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,dcolumn,booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable, tabulary, tabularx, placeins,tocloft,tocbibind}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}}



\begin{document}
\begin{threeparttable}\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xsss|ssss}
\toprule
$\alpha$                &  & $ 1 $ & $ 2 $ & $ 3 $ & $ 4 $ & $ 5 $ & $ 6 $  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you do this with just `tabularx` shoul I find more explanation in tabluarx docs? Especially the meaning of this: `>{\centering\arraybackslash`?

Comment: @snoram I'm not sure what you mean by "just tabularx" the above only uses tabularx, the `>` syntax should be described in any latex tutorial, it comes from the array package there are multiple examples in the array and tabularx doc and this site (it just inserts the centering code into each cell in that column).

Comment: Sorry, I meant is what does this solution depend on apart from `tabularx`. I assume that, for example, I need to load the `array` package?

Comment: @snoram for `>` yes or without `array` just put `\centering` in each cell directly